# Se me cierra el buscador cuando intento abrirlo con webdriver de la libreria selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Este es el codigo

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://www.mexx.com.ar/productos-rubro/placas-de-video/36970-placa-de-video-geforce-gtx-1660-6gb-msi-super-ventus-xs-oc.html"
```

En esta linea probe con escribir el path de chrome pero no me abre la pagina en el buscador ,y en el codigo asi como esta se me cierra instantaneamente el buscador aunque si abre el link que le paso por medio de la variable url

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: si tu codigo finaliza entonces se cierra el navegador agregale un:
while true: pass

Answer (score 1):

probé distintas combinaciones y me di cuenta que cuándo no se agrega otra línea al código, webdriver al parecer lo toma como que el código ya finalizó, por ende se cierra de inmediato. Prueba agregando un input después de declarar el webdriver.

```
#PRUEBA DE ERROR
driver.get('www.google.cl')

input("Esperando que no se cierre webdriver: ")
```

También te recomiendo usar ChromeDriveManager en tu código para que cuando exista una actualización de Google Chrome, webdriver sea capaz de actualizarse por si solo y no tener que hacer el proceso de manera manual.

```
#Set de instalación y actualización de chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Espero mi respuesta responda tu consulta, un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

El error es debido a que la versión de chromedriver no es compatible con tu versión de google chrome, descarga una versión mas antigua de chromedriver, a mi me ocurrió el mismo error y así lo solucione.